# Topic directive won't display correctly (using "agogo" theme)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm creating documentation using Sphinx and reStructuredtext. I want to use the topic directive to make important information on a page more noticeable.

```
Stuff
=====
Things I need to say.

.. topic:: before using this:

    -You must do the thing

    -Do the other thing

Continue
========

Other stuff
```

But the output of is:

**Stuff**

Things I need to say.

before using this:

-You must do the thing

-Do the other thing

**Continue**

What am I doing wrong with the topic directive that it's not working? I have one argument, an empty line between the directive call and the topics body. The html build and isn't throwing any errors.

Comment: I think a screenshot would help. What is the problem with the "topic box" when the bullets have been fixed? What theme do you use?

Comment: @mzjn, I want a box to surround the bullets, in several places I have seen people use the topic directive to surround the following text/bullets in a box. I'm using agogo.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the agogo theme's default display of topics isn't very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reStructuredText bullet list items require white space immediately after the bullet.  See [Bullet Lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists).

To fix:

```
Stuff
=====
Things I need to say.

.. topic:: before using this:

    - You must do the thing

    - Do the other thing

Continue
========

Other stuff
```

Comment: This helped with the bullets, but how do I get the topic box to show up around it

Comment: Does your theme support topic? If not then you either have to switch to a theme that does use it or add your own custom CSS.

Comment: I think the theme I'm using, agogo, doesn't support it